# Favorite action getting error: Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, arguments

I had a working favorite action where my users could favorite a room but now I'm getting this error and I dont know why it is not working?

**How can I make this work?**

[image]

**show.html.erb**

```
   <% if current_user && current_user.favorites.exists(@room) %>
      <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_room_path(@room, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
   <% else %>
      <%= link_to "favorite", favorite_room_path(@room, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
   <% end %>
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
  before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :favorite]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:favorite]

  def show
    @photos = @room.photos

    @booked = Reservation.where("room_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @room.id, current_user.id).present? if current_user

    @reviews = @room.reviews
    @hasReview = @reviews.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) if current_user
  end

  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @room unless current_user.favorites.exists?(@room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'You favorited #{@room.listing_name}'
    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@room.listing_name}'
    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end


  private
    def set_room
      @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is include:

```
if current_user && current_user.favorites.include?(@room)
```

Comment: @trickydiddy no probs! Make sure to accept the answer if it worked for you